# What could be the title of a power point presentation for a PostDoc Interview?

Tags: etiquette, postdocs, presentation

Postdoctoral research jobs always ask to make a presentation of past and present research and future plan. So I am wondering what could be the title of such type of power point presentations. Is it Okay to keep the title of the PhD thesis? Or it should be blank or something else? Would you please share your experiences.

Field: Atmospheric Science

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a somewhat standard talk title. If you're presenting primarily the results of a single paper, I don't know that it would be a problem to use the title of the paper as the title of the presentation.

For reference, the titles of some of my interview talks:

- *Adventures in Modeling for Policy*
- *Harnessing the Counterfactual*
- *Hospital Infection Control: Integrating Mathematical and Observational Epidemiology*

All of these seemed to go over just fine.